# This is a question about how springDataElasticSearch divides buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
        NativeSearchQuery build1 = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withFilter(rangeQuery("releaseDate").gte(1538841600000L).lte(1539446400000L))
                .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("releaseDate").field("releaseDate").dateHistogramInterval(DateHistogramInterval.DAY)
                        .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("type").field("sourceType")))
                .build();
```

[image]

I hope to achieve the same effect through code
my springdataElasticSearch version is 3.2.3RELEASE

Comment: What query does your code produce and how does it differ from the one from your screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem..

`NativeSearchQuery build1 = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()                  .withQuery(boolQuery().filter(rangeQuery("releaseDate").gte(1538841600000L).lte(1539446400000L)))          .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("ReleaseDate").field("releaseDate").dateHistogramInterval(DateHistogramInterval.DAY).subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("Type").field("sourceType")))`